# Shared library versioning with cmake on github

Tags: linux, github, cmake, shared-libraries, semantic-versioning

I have a fairly new project on github that produces a shared library. Going forward, I would like to use semantic versioning (as described at [semver.org](https://semver.org/)) for the shared library major/minor/patch numbers in the file name. The project uses CMake. The CMakeLists.txt file refers to CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR, CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR and CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH, and sets these to default values if they are not passed in on the command line.

My plan is to branch on ABI changes and API additions, according to semantic versioning principles.

I know github has support for creating and naming release packages containing the project source based on git tags. But I do not see a way to propagate the major, minor and patch numbers to the shared library name when the github user builds a release on their machine.

For example, if I have a branch called, myproj_1_2, and a release tag called myproj_rel_1_2_9, is there a way to have the shared library built by a user be name libmyproj.so.1.2.9?

Is this just a matter of documenting that a user should pass the build name information on the cmake command line, and the have the CMakeLists.txt file parse this and set CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR, CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR and CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH accordingly, or is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: No two collections of bits should ever have the same name and version numbers if any of their contents vary by even a single bit. Most build systems are incapable of producing exactly the same inputs from the same source code when user/machine names, root paths or start/end times are varied...

Comment: Therefore, it is folly to attempt consistent versioning of outputs across users, machines, root paths and start/stop times that does not incorporate a cryptographically secure hash of all the inputs, including; user, machine, root paths, start/stop times and any of the other unenumerable reasons that build systems yield non-deterministic results.

Comment: <Opinion>Only official build systems should be allowed to produce anything that looks like a release version!</Opinion>. The easiest thing to do is to always force a prerelease tag or use 0.0.0. Official builds would then add the additional step of copying/renaming the library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement about how CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_XXX is set is incorrect. The CPack variables in question are set by the `project` command if the `project` command specifies versioning.  So when you create the 1.2.9 branch you would set 1.2.9 as the version number in the project command.

From [CPack Help](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html)

> CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR
>
> Package major version. This variable will always be set, but its default value depends on whether or not version details were given to
>   the project() command in the top level CMakeLists.txt file. If version
>   details were given, the default value will be
>   CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR. If no version details were given, a
>   default version of 0.1.1 will be assumed, leading to
>   CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR having a default value of 0.

[Project command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html)

```
> project(<PROJECT-NAME>
>         [VERSION <major>[.<minor>[.<patch>[.<tweak>]]]]
>         [DESCRIPTION <project-description-string>]
>         [HOMEPAGE_URL <url-string>]
>         [LANGUAGES <language-name>...])
```

If you don't want to set the VERSION via the project command then there are multiple other ways of setting the relevant variables.

Examples are located:
https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/

Also look at how CMake handles versions:

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Source/CMakeVersionSource.cmake

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Source/cmVersionConfig.h.in

Another example of how to get git meta data for setting version related information:
https://github.com/pmirshad/cmake-with-git-metadata/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Thank you. I can play with using the project command to set versioning, per the excerpts you cited. But, I have not found any documentation that says CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR should not be modified after the project. Googling, I see several examples of this. That's not to say it's correct...Regardless, I don't believe it's relevant to my issue. My issue is, is there a way such that when someone downloads and builds the github project for the resulting shared library to have the correct versioning in its name?

Comment: I've added additional examples on how to set the version in CMake.  It seemed straight forward to set the VERSION field in the project command.  You also seem to be concerned with preventing someone from changing the version number after it has been downloaded.  You can't enforce what they do to modify the variables and change the version.

Comment: I'm not so concerned about changing things after they've downloaded it. I just wanted the library to have the correct version number in the name when they build it on  their own machine. One of the examples you provided clicked for me on this. The CMakeLists.txt can call something like "git describe" to get tags, and then parse the tags to get the major, minor and patch number to use with cmake, so the shared lib will have the correct name. I think what threw me off was I was thinking about building outside of the context of git. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure.  Take a good look at how CMake does it's versioning because it can detect if your are building from a tarball or from git.  If it detects that source folder is git it'll take version (and if it is dirty) into account or use the values specified in a file supplied in the tarball.